# Problem building a docker container with Haskell-stack: How can I ensure that Haskell-stack continues building till the end?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, cabal, haskell-stack

Here is what happened: I built a docker image with stack, but the process got interrupted five times. The message said that each interruption happened while building package Cabal-2.4.1.0. The process exited with code: `ExitFailure (-9) (THIS MAY INDICATE OUT OF MEMORY)`.

I want to automate the process in a docker-script, so it is essential that stack makes it to the end. That is my problem. Here is what happened when building (I left out some lines to keep your scrolling within reasonable limits, so expect to see `<...  skipping <n> lines  ...>`) every now and then. (to be continued at the bottom.)

```
BA92-C02VP224HTDF:Ampersand stefjoosten$ docker build -t amp:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  70.28MB
Step 1/8 : FROM ubuntu:latest
 ---> 7698f282e524
Step 2/8 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get --yes install curl &&     apt-get --yes install git-core
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 81322e02eb2a
Step 3/8 : RUN curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh   # install Haskell and stack
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0ff9ca0665b9
Step 4/8 : WORKDIR /Ampersand/                                # build from the Ampersand source code directory
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a66b539a6868
Step 5/8 : RUN git clone https://github.com/AmpersandTarski/Ampersand/ .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1806c9a40c82
Step 6/8 : RUN git checkout feature/rio-phase2                # get Ampersand sources in the correct version
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 456074437186
Step 7/8 : RUN stack setup                                    # set up Haskell stack (version taken from stack.yaml)
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fcadefd6812c
Step 8/8 : RUN stack install                                  # installs Ampersand executables in /root/.local/bin
 ---> Running in 0a8d298a757c
Updating package index Hackage (mirrored at https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackage.fpcomplete.com/) ...
Selected mirror https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackage.fpcomplete.com/
Downloading root
Selected mirror https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackage.fpcomplete.com/
Downloading timestamp
Downloading snapshot
Downloading mirrors
Cannot update index (no local copy)
Downloading index
Updated package index downloaded
Update complete
Populating index cache ...
Populated index cache.
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( /root/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-mPHDZzAJ.hs, /root/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-mPHDZzAJ.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling StackSetupShim   ( /root/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs, /root/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.o )
Linking /root/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/tmp-Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.4 ...
Cabal-2.4.1.0: download
StateVar-1.1.1.1: download
HsYAML-0.1.1.3: download
StateVar-1.1.1.1: configure
SHA-1.6.4.4: download
StateVar-1.1.1.1: build
HsYAML-0.1.1.3: configure
HsYAML-0.1.1.3: build
Cabal-2.4.1.0: configure
StateVar-1.1.1.1: copy/register

<...  skipping 55 lines  ...>

cereal-0.5.8.0: download
cereal-0.5.8.0: configure
cereal-0.5.8.0: build
basement-0.0.10: copy/register
cereal-0.5.8.0: copy/register
blaze-html-0.9.1.1: copy/register

--  While building package Cabal-2.4.1.0 using:
      /root/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.4 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure (-9) (THIS MAY INDICATE OUT OF MEMORY)
    Logs have been written to: /Ampersand/                                # build from the Ampersand source code directory/.stack-work/logs/Cabal-2.4.1.0.log

    Configuring Cabal-2.4.1.0...
    Preprocessing library for Cabal-2.4.1.0..
    Building library for Cabal-2.4.1.0..
    [  1 of 220] Compiling Distribution.Compat.Binary ( Distribution/Compat/Binary.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Distribution/Compat/Binary.o )
    [  2 of 220] Compiling Distribution.Compat.Directory ( Distribution/Compat/Directory.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Distribution/Compat/Directory.o )
    [  3 of 220] Compiling Distribution.Compat.Exception ( Distribution/Compat/Exception.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Distribution/Compat/Exception.o )
    [  4 of 220] Compiling Distribution.Compat.Internal.TempFile ( Distribution/Compat/Internal/TempFile.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Distribution/Compat/Internal/TempFile.o )
    [  5 of 220] Compiling Distribution.Compat.MonadFail ( Distribution/Compat/MonadFail.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Distribution/Compat/MonadFail.o )
    [  6 of 220] Compiling Distribution.Compat.Newtype ( Distribution/Compat/Newtype.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Distribution/Compat/Newtype.o )

<...  skipping 56 lines  ...>

    [ 63 of 220] Compiling Distribution.System ( Distribution/System.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Distribution/System.o )
    [ 64 of 220] Compiling Distribution.SPDX.LicenseReference ( Distribution/SPDX/LicenseReference.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Distribution/SPDX/LicenseReference.o )
    [ 65 of 220] Compiling Distribution.SPDX.LicenseId ( Distribution/SPDX/LicenseId.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Distribution/SPDX/LicenseId.o )
The command '/bin/sh -c stack install                                  # installs Ampersand executables in /root/.local/bin' returned a non-zero code: 1
BA92-C02VP224HTDF:Ampersand stefjoosten$ docker start  `docker ps -q -l` # restart it in the background
0a8d298a757c
BA92-C02VP224HTDF:Ampersand stefjoosten$ docker attach `docker ps -q -l`
cmark-gfm-0.1.8: build
clock-0.7.2: copy/register
colour-2.3.4: download
colour-2.3.4: configure
colour-2.3.4: build

<...  skipping 200 lines  ...>

primitive-0.6.4.0: copy/register
reflection-2.1.4: copy/register
hxt-9.3.1.16: copy/register

--  While building package Cabal-2.4.1.0 using:
      /root/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.4 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure (-9) (THIS MAY INDICATE OUT OF MEMORY)
    Logs have been written to: /Ampersand/                                # build from the Ampersand source code directory/.stack-work/logs/Cabal-2.4.1.0.log

    Configuring Cabal-2.4.1.0...
    Preprocessing library for Cabal-2.4.1.0..
    Building library for Cabal-2.4.1.0..
    [  1 of 220] Compiling Distribution.Compat.Binary ( Distribution/Compat/Binary.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Distribution/Compat/Binary.o )
    [  2 of 220] Compiling Distribution.Compat.Directory ( Distribution/Compat/Directory.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Distribution/Compat/Directory.o )
    [  3 of 220] Compiling Distribution.Compat.Exception ( Distribution/Compat/Exception.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Distribution/Compat/Exception.o )
    [  4 of 220] Compiling Distribution.Compat.Internal.TempFile ( Distribution/Compat/Internal/TempFile.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Distribution/Compat/Internal/TempFile.o )
    [  5 of 220] Compiling Distribution.Compat.MonadFail ( Distribution/Compat/MonadFail.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Distribution/Compat/MonadFail.o )
    [  6 of 220] Compiling Distribution.Compat.Newtype ( Distribution/Compat/Newtype.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Distribution/Compat/Newtype.o )

<...  skipping 104 lines  ...>

    [111 of 220] Compiling Distribution.Types.AbiDependency ( Distribution/Types/AbiDependency.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Distribution/Types/AbiDependency.o )
    [112 of 220] Compiling Distribution.Simple.InstallDirs ( Distribution/Simple/InstallDirs.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Distribution/Simple/InstallDirs.o )
    [113 of 220] Compiling Distribution.Types.LegacyExeDependency ( Distribution/Types/LegacyExeDependency.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Distribution/Types/LegacyExeDependency.o )
    [114 of 220] Compiling Distribution.Types.BuildInfo ( Distribution/Types/BuildInfo.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Distribution/Types/BuildInfo.o )
BA92-C02VP224HTDF:Ampersand stefjoosten$ docker start  `docker ps -q -l` # restart it in the background
0a8d298a757c
BA92-C02VP224HTDF:Ampersand stefjoosten$ docker attach `docker ps -q -l`
regex-base-0.93.2: copy/register
regex-pcre-builtin-0.94.4.8.8.35: download

<...  skipping 678 lines with three more interruptions  ...>

pandoc-2.5: copy/register
pandoc-crossref-0.3.4.0: download
pandoc-crossref-0.3.4.0: configure
pandoc-crossref-0.3.4.0: build
pandoc-crossref-0.3.4.0: copy/register
Building all executables for `ampersand' once. After a successful build of all of them, only specified executables will be rebuilt.
ampersand-3.17.0: configure (lib + exe)
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( /Ampersand/                                # build from the Ampersand source code directory/Setup.hs, /Ampersand/                                # build from the Ampersand source code directory/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/setup/Main.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling StackSetupShim   ( /root/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs, /Ampersand/                                # build from the Ampersand source code directory/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/setup/StackSetupShim.o )
Linking /Ampersand/                                # build from the Ampersand source code directory/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/setup/setup ...
Configuring ampersand-3.17.0...
ampersand-3.17.0: build (lib + exe)



Warning: Cannot read previously generated src/Ampersand/Prototype/StaticFiles_Generated.hs:
src/Ampersand/Prototype/StaticFiles_Generated.hs: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
This warning should disappear the next time you build Ampersand. If the error persists, please report this as a bug.

Static files have changed, updating src/Ampersand/Prototype/StaticFiles_Generated.hs

Preprocessing library for ampersand-3.17.0..
Building library for ampersand-3.17.0..
[  1 of 113] Compiling Ampersand.Basics.Prelude ( src/Ampersand/Basics/Prelude.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Ampersand/Basics/Prelude.o )
[  2 of 113] Compiling Ampersand.Basics.Languages ( src/Ampersand/Basics/Languages.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Ampersand/Basics/Languages.o )
[  3 of 113] Compiling Ampersand.Basics.Exit ( src/Ampersand/Basics/Exit.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Ampersand/Basics/Exit.o )
[  4 of 113] Compiling Ampersand.Basics.BuildInfo_Generated ( src/Ampersand/Basics/BuildInfo_Generated.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Ampersand/Basics/BuildInfo_Generated.o )
[  5 of 113] Compiling Ampersand.Basics.Auxiliaries ( src/Ampersand/Basics/Auxiliaries.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Ampersand/Basics/Auxiliaries.o )
[  6 of 113] Compiling Ampersand.Basics.String ( src/Ampersand/Basics/String.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Ampersand/Basics/String.o )

<...  skipping 103 lines  ...>

[110 of 113] Compiling Ampersand.Test   ( src/Ampersand/Test.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Ampersand/Test.o )
[111 of 113] Compiling Ampersand        ( src/Ampersand.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Ampersand.o )
[112 of 113] Compiling MainApps         ( src/MainApps.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/MainApps.o )
[113 of 113] Compiling Paths_ampersand  ( .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/autogen/Paths_ampersand.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Paths_ampersand.o )
Preprocessing executable 'ampersand' for ampersand-3.17.0..
Building executable 'ampersand' for ampersand-3.17.0..
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( app/Ampersand/Main.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/ampersand/ampersand-tmp/Main.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Paths_ampersand  ( .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/ampersand/autogen/Paths_ampersand.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/ampersand/ampersand-tmp/Paths_ampersand.o )
Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/ampersand/ampersand ...
ampersand-3.17.0: copy/register
Installing library in /Ampersand/                                # build from the Ampersand source code directory/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-13.16/8.6.4/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.6.4/ampersand-3.17.0-K72VvTMgyU7EFfE6avLPOe
Installing executable ampersand in /Ampersand/                                # build from the Ampersand source code directory/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-13.16/8.6.4/bin
Registering library for ampersand-3.17.0..
Completed 25 action(s).
Copying from /Ampersand/                                # build from the Ampersand source code directory/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-13.16/8.6.4/bin/ampersand to /root/.local/bin/ampersand

Copied executables to /root/.local/bin:
- ampersand
```

It is strange to see the building process interrupted for the (possible) reason of memory exhaustion, but the process happily continues after the docker-build process is restarted. I needed 5 restarts to get to the end.

I tried to increase docker's memory, experimenting with the commands:

```
docker build -m 4g -t amp:latest .
docker build -m 12g -t amp:latest .
```

but that makes no noteworthy difference.

I'd be grateful for any ideas...

Comment: Could you finally find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to pass `--jobs 1` to `stack`.  This will turn off concurrent builds which will reduce the memory requirements.  GHC is generally a memory hog, and some code in particular really uses a lot of memory to compile.  What's probably happening is that two modules that both take a lot of memory are ending up being built at the same time, and when that happens you'll end up with the OOM.  But each time you run the build, a few more packages get built and the build order can change, so eventually you luck out and the memory hogs don't end up building concurrently, so the build is able to finish.

Comment: Thanks Emanuel, I tried that. Actually `--jobs 1` made things a lot worse. The interrupt occurs a lot earlier. I tried `--jobs 2` also, which makes it slightly better, but still a lot worse. This is contrary to what I'd expect, based on your (very plausible) argument....